python filename fails due to escape character
I would like to read a filename.
The string should be converted to a valid filename.
However the input to the conversion fails.
xlsfile = base64.urlsafe_b64encode('C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\Dokumente\20241023-1904097928-umsatz.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(xlsfile)

The problem is the sequence "\20".
How can I ensure that the file is read?
Error message is: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

is the error in the first line, or the second ?
if it is on the first line, is it on the function or the link?

On the first line with xlsfile

\U is the escape prefix for Unicode strings. Either escape the backslashes, use forward slashes, or use a raw string.

\20 would be an error, if \U wasn't incorrectly used earlier in the string.

raw string: r".." was the solution.
